# SPARQL: enumerate result list

Tags: sparql, wikidata

For simplicity I use wikidata as example: I have a [query](https://w.wiki/4pEB):

```sql
SELECT  ?item ?itemLabel ?mastoadress
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P4033 ?mastoadress.
  ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q1930187. # occupation journalist
  ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q183. # country of citizenship germany
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
}
ORDER BY ?itemLabel
```

How can I achieve the result list to include a column where each entry gets its own unique integer index.

Comment: that's not part of SPARQL standard

Comment: @UninformedUser OK. But isnt there a hack to achieve this?

Comment: sure: `SELECT (count(?item2) as ?idx) ?item ?itemLabel ?mastoadress
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P4033 ?mastoadress.
  ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q1930187. 
  ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q183.
  {SELECT ?item2 {
   ?item2 wdt:P4033 ?mastoadress2.
  ?item2 wdt:P106 wd:Q1930187. 
  ?item2 wdt:P27 wd:Q183.
    }}
  FILTER(str(?item2) < str(?item))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 

}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?mastoadress
ORDER BY ?idx`

Comment: for efficiency reasons, you should consider a Blazegraph extension like named subquery (alternatively you could use a query hint) to run the subquery just once

Comment: `SELECT (count(?item2) as ?idx) ?item ?itemLabel ?mastoadress
WITH {
  SELECT ?item2 {
   ?item2 wdt:P4033 ?mastoadress2.
  ?item2 wdt:P106 wd:Q1930187. 
  ?item2 wdt:P27 wd:Q183.
    }
  } AS %items
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P4033 ?mastoadress.
  ?item wdt:P106 wd:Q1930187. 
  ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q183.
  INCLUDE %items
  FILTER(str(?item2) < str(?item))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 

}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?mastoadress
ORDER BY ?idx`